# What are the advantages & disadvantages on using Samsung Corby for Android App development?

Tags: android

I want to use Samsung Corby to develop a location-based app. I want to know the things that this phone model can offer and the possible issues that I might encounter with it. It's a cheap phone and is available in our country, that's why I chose it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you @Pentium10. I'll do that. :D

Answer (score 0):

The main disadvantage is that the Samsung Corby (S3650) doesn't run Android...

Comment: http://androidandme.com/2010/06/phones/samsung/samsung-corby-smartphone-bringing-android-to-the-masses/ - dont know if this model is now available here.

Comment: @jalbautista now I'm feeling lucky I'm Italian :-)

Comment: lucky you! :D. I saw a Samsung phone running Android. I might try that. :D